# display name of color variant in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

We use color swatches on our Shopify project. We are looking for a solution, to display only the name of the selected color variant. Is it possible to implement this with liquid or do we need a JavaScript solution?

**Take a look where that should take place: [printnil.com](http://printnil.com/products/angebotsmappe?variant=1052118699)**

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
<span>{{ variant.title }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change what you are displaying based on the user's selection, you'll need to use JavaScript. Take a look at [this tutorial in the Shopify docs](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-make-my-theme-use-products-with-multiple-options) that explains how to create a callback that is called whenever the user changes their selection (you may already have this in your theme):

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  <your code goes here>
}
```

You can access the variant's options within this callback. E.g. If Colour is the first option, use `variant.option1` to get the currently selected colour.